# C++ Image filtering algorithm

Tags: c++, arrays, image, algorithm, filter

I'm busy trying to implement an image filtering algorithm that works as follows:
A filter is a 2-dimensional array of size N (N has to be an odd number), therefore having N*N elements. An example filter of size 3 would be:

```
0.25 1 0.25
0.25 0 0.25
0.25 1 0.25
```

For every unsigned char (pixel) in the image data, place the center of the filter array at the current working pixel. Then for every pixel that the filter covers in the image, find the weighted sum of all the pixels covered by the filter (i.e each filter value multiplied by the pixel it is currently covering) and set your current working image pixel value to that weighted sum. Do this for every pixel in the image. If a filter pixel falls out of range of the image 2D array (i.e off left, right, top, bottom), then it must wrap around the appropriate edge of the image.

So I have the following code:

```
Image Image::operator%(const Filter & g) {
    Image filtered = *this;
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> filter = g.get_filter();
    Image::iterator beg = filtered.begin();
    Image::iterator end = filtered.end();
    unsigned char* pixel_data = filtered.data.get();
    int pixel_index = 0;

    while(beg != end) {
        // current working pixel value
        unsigned char* c_pixel = *beg;

        float weight = 0;

        // starting x and y position (top left) relative to the centre
        // of the filter at index 'pixel'
        int start_y = pixel_index - (g.get_size()-1) / 2;
        int start_x = pixel_index - (g.get_size()-1) / 2;

        for(int row = 0; row < g.get_size(); ++row) {
            std::vector<float> r = filter.at(row);
            int c_row = start_y + row;

            if(c_row >= height) {
                c_row %= height;
            } else if(c_row < 0) {
                c_row += height;
            }

            for(int col = 0; col < g.get_size(); ++col) {
                // current column of filter relative
                // to the image pixel
                int c_col = start_x + col;

                if(c_col >= width) {
                    c_col %= width;
                } else if(c_col < 0) {
                    c_col += width;
                }
                weight += pixel_data[this->index(c_col, c_row)]*r.at(col);
            }
        }
        *c_pixel = weight;
        ++beg;
        ++pixel_index;
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

In-case you are wondering, `this->index(c_col, c_row)` is treating a 1D array as a 2D array:

```
int Image::index(int x, int y) {
    return width*y + x;
}
```

... and the image data is protected by a `std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]>`.
This code gives me some strange output. The resulting image has vertical streaks of different pixel colors, somewhat resembling the original image color. I have no idea what I am doing wrong, because this method checks out on paper but not in code. I'll be glad to add any extra information if needed. :)

Comment: _"because this method checks out on paper but not in code"_ Did you already step through with your debugger?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't use an IDE, I use Sublime text...

Comment: Well there is gdb, you can use from the command line?

Comment: And gdbtui for a "more user friendly" approach

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks, I'll check it out

Comment: Would be interesting to see some **original** vs **result** images. Good luck.

Comment: TLDR the code. Two common mistakes: 1) The output array is the same as the input array. That's (almost) always bad. 2) the sum of the weights is greater than 1, as in your example. That can cause your calculations to overflow. Or if you saturate at 255, then you end up with a whole lot of white pixels.

Comment: Essentially, you are performing a convolution. If your kernel is N pixels tall, rather than have an `if` statement for every pixel (which stalls the CPU while it does the test), folks often start the loop at row `N/2` and end at row `H-N/2` and do the edges in a separate loop. It's just an optimisation.

Answer (score 2):

My first concern is the image pixel format.  You say the output is `std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]>`, but the weight is computed and written using floats. Your `index` method returns an index without taking into account the pixel data size { 1_BYTE (monochrome), 3_BYTE (RGB8), 4_Byte(RGBA8) }.  `pixel_data` is char (Byte) so I'm not certain you are indexing the pixel data correctly, not taking into account pixel size and not ignoring alpha (if needed).

The other concern is that if you are using RGB(a) data, then conversion from INT->Float isn't going to scale correctly.  Multiplying by float will scale the pixel as a solid number and not the channels individually.  This will result in channels spilling into each other and generally not being correct.

Your next step is to create a filter that reads and writes the data as pixels with RGB channels (ignoring alpha) to make sure your filter is pass-thru.  Then, you will write a filter that removes an RGB channel by setting it to 0 or 255. (Red Channel, Blue Channel, Green Channel)

Once you are certain that you can manipulate RGB separately and correctly, then you can start applying weights.

The first attempt will be slow. Eventually you will find out that you can use MASKs to grab R_B channel separate from G channel and you won't worry about overflow.  This magic looks generally like this:

```
    UInt32 WeightPixel(UInt32 value, float weight)
    {
        const UInt32 MASK1 = (UInt32)0x00ff00ff; // _R_B
        const UInt32 MASK2 = (UInt32)0xff00ff00; // A_G_

        int f2 = (int)(256 * weight); // Scale weight into char range

        // >> 8 is just divide by 256
        return (UInt32)(((((value & MASK1) * f2)) >> 8) & MASK1)
               | (UInt32)(((((value & MASK2) * f2)) >> 8) & MASK2);
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the images are of the ".pgm" format, so they are all greyscale - we don't need to work with RGB values. Also, when working with unsigned chars, surely indexing an array at a specific value will always return the unsigned char at that index, or any other data type?

Comment: With single-byte, grayscale images, yes.  The indexing and calculations should be fine.  I would start investigating oversaturation as mentioned by@user3386109 (divide all weights by 3.5f before setting to pixel output)

Comment: I think it may have to do with loss of precision when multiplying the unsigned char with the float. How would I go about doing this precisely? Is there any place I can post example input and output images? Stackoverflow doesn't support .pgm format.

Comment: Install ImageMagick to your command line, an invaluable set of tools for converting, mogrify, etc...  As for conversion, I think char gets upconverted to float in your calculation, but then truncated when being stuffed back into char.  When you want to be explicit about the type, wrap it with parenthesis and specify the type. `int(pixel_data[0])` or `((int)pixel_data[0])`